# get youtube link between two values and replace with iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

if there's a html like the following

```
<div class="comment">
[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid1[/youtube]
random text
</div>
<div class="comment">
[youtube]http://youtu.be/videoid2[/youtube]
random text2
</div>
```

how using jquery could you extract the youtube video id from links for each `.comment` element between **[youtube]** to **[/youtube]** to create an embedded player so the outcome will be

```
<div class="comment">
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid1?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
random text
</div>
<div class="comment">
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid2?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
random text2
</div>
```

Comment: @Ktash sorry forgot to mention , but doesnt matter Rob W has answered it

Comment: Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/aY9XF/7/. I'm using .text() to show you how it would put together. But when using .html() it still wont render the code. I don't know why though.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a RegExp (not fool-proof) + the jQuery `.each()` and `.html()` methods to achieve this.

```
var youtubeTag = /\[youtube]https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtu(?:be\.com|\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=|v\/)?([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)([a-zA-Z&=;_+0-9*#-]*?)\[\/youtube]/,
    youtubeHTML = '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$(".comment").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(youtubeTag, youtubeHTML))
});
```

The pattern matches:

- `[youtube]`
- Starting with `http://` or `https://`
- Optionally, followed by `www.`
- Either: `youtube.com`, `youtu.be`
- Followed by a slash (`/`)
- Optionally: `watch?v=` or `v/`
- A YouTube video ID (All alphanumeric characters, underscore and hyphen)
- Optionally followed by another part of the query string / location hash
- `[/youtube]`

Comment: I have a question what if a link has &feature=grec_index at the end of it this will not work for e.g **[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=videoid1&feature=grec_index[/youtube]** http://jsfiddle.net/yusaf/uLTzw/1/

Comment: @Yusaf I've updated my answer. Beware of creating too relax patterns (ie NOT `.*?`, especially NOT `.*`), because these may also unexpectely match `[youtube]....watch?v=4568wa not a part of the URL blabla[/youtube]`